# Search function returns the same result multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, search, for-loop, mysqli

I'm trying to create a search function in PHP, however come across a slight problem. When I enter a single search term, I get the expected result (single record, single search result listed), but when I enter 2 or more valid search terms I get the same record listed multiple times. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong please?

```
public function product_search($search_terms)
{
    $search_terms = htmlspecialchars($search_terms);
    $search_terms = stripslashes($search_terms);
    $search_terms_array = explode(" ", $search_terms);
    $terms_count = count($search_terms_array);
    $zerocount = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $terms_count; $i++)
    {
        $search_terms_array = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);
        ${"query".$i} = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT * FROM sjs_product_list WHERE prod_tags LIKE '%" . $search_terms_array[$i] . "%'");
        if(${"query".$i}->num_rows < 1)
        {
            $zerocount++;
        }
        else
        {
            while($row = ${"query".$i}->fetch_array())
            {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                echo "<h3><a href=\"index.php?section=products&amp;subsection=" . $row['prod_category'] . "&amp;prodid=" . $row['prod_id'] . "\">" . $row['prod_name'] . "</h3></a><img src=\"includes/images/product_images/" . $row['prod_category'] . "/" . $row['prod_pic_filename'] . "\" alt=\"\"/><p>Price: " . $row['prod_price'] . "</p><p>" . $row['prod_code'] . "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
    if($zerocount == $terms_count)
    {
        echo "<h3>Your search terms returned 0 results. Please try using different search terms.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're replacing the array with a string when you do `$search_terms_array = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);`

Comment: Learn about arrays. You should use `$query[$i]` instead of `${"query".$i}`. Arrays are a fundamental concept in practically all programming languages.

Comment: Actually, there's no need to use different variables for each query result. You can just reuse the same `$query` variable each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$search_terms_array = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);
```

to

```
$search_terms_array[$i] = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);
```

You were replacing the whole array with just its first element. Then when you used `$search_terms_array[$i]` after this, you were just getting the `i`th chararacter of this string.

Another problem: you're not clearing the `$rows` array each time through the loop. Put:

```
$rows = array();
```

before

```
while ($row = ${"query".$i}->fetch_array())
```

You're printing the whole `$rows` array inside the loop, so each time you're printing the rows from the previous iteration as well, even though they were already printed.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for that, made the change however still getting the same issue. Only have one record in the database for test purposes, however if I put in 2 search terms it returns the record 3 times, if I put in 3 search terms it returns the record 6 times. If I put in all 5 search terms related to the record it returns the record 15 times?

Comment: Am still getting to grips with OOP and arrays so bear with me on this one :)

Comment: I don't see any way that this code could do that. Is it possible you're calling `product_search` multiple times?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(4) "blah" }

Comment: Ok that's sorted that thank you! I can now have a play with the code to stop it returning the same record for each search term.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace below two lines in your code:-**

```
<?php 
$search_key = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);
${"query".$i} = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT * FROM sjs_product_list WHERE prod_tags LIKE '%" . $search_key  . "%'");
?>
```